# Give a color when my input its not expanded and other color when it is expanded

Tags: html, css

I have a form, and when I click in my input the input expands.

I want to give color #000 when my input is not expanded, and color #fff when input is expanded.

I think I'm doing it correctly but it's not working: why?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SJsN9/1/)

```
<form id="search">
  <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Pesquisar..." />
</form>
```

My CSS:

```
#search input[type="text"] 
{
    border: 0 none;
    text-indent: 0;
    background:green;
    width:80px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    color:#000;

}

#search input[type="text"]:focus 
{
    background: #141d22;
    width: 110px;
    outline:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `::input-placeholder` pseudo class. You will need specific vendor prefixes for each browser.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/p4jqN/) - see example for other prefixed selectors.

```
#search input[type="text"]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:#fff;
}
#search input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:#000;
}
```